# Should I use DialogFragment to show a dialog?

Tags: android

If I want to show the dialog, I can just write these code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.show();
```

But when I see the API, it says that we should create a class to inherit `DialogFragment`. So my question is should I always use the `DialogFragment` class? And in which case I can only use this class?

Comment: For the built-in simple types (Alert, Progress. Confirmation etc) you can use Dialog builders. However, if you want to show your own UI in a dialog, it is recommended to create a `DialogFragment`. Dialog fragments can also be embedded in an Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you should not requried to use DialogFragment everytime. You can Use this.

```
public void showSimpleInfoAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String msg) {


        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        AlertDialog dialog;
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
        builder.setMessage(msg);

        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

               //your stuff
                dialog.dismiss();


            }
        });


        dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using this library (https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs) that is really pleasant to work with.  It reduces codebase and ensures consistent look.  You can also customize its content/behaviour for more complex cases, e.g. custom lists or listeners

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem ,,,i had to implement a login dialog and i did the following and it works like a charm,,,give it a try

This was my login dialog Layout XML contents you can design your layout ,,its upto you

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:hint="Username or Email"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/facebook_login"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="#3b5998"
    android:text="Login via Facebook"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/twitter_login"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/facebook_normal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="#55ACEE"
    android:text="Login via Twitter"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/google_login"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/twitter"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="#D64534"
    android:text="Login via Google"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/cancel_button"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/cancel_button"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textColor="#009688" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="30sp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColor="#009688"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

after this all you need to do is inflate this Layout in dialogBuilder as below

```
{
  LayoutInflater linf = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

            final View inflator = linf.inflate(R.layout.login_dialog, null);

            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

            fLogin = (Button) inflator.findViewById(R.id.facebook_login);
            gLogin = (Button) inflator.findViewById(R.id.google_login);
            tLogin = (Button) inflator.findViewById(R.id.twitter_login);
            loginButton = (Button)   inflator.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
            cancelButton = (Button) inflator.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
            uName = (TextView) inflator.findViewById(R.id.username);
            pwd = (TextView) inflator.findViewById(R.id.password);

   /** You can handle click events here**//
    builder.setView(inflator).show();
   }
```

hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [Dialogs guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) it is recommended that you always use DialogFragment class. DialogFragment will handle the app's lifecycle events and provide the correct behavior.

check this extract from the documentation

> but you should use a DialogFragment as a container for your dialog.
>   The DialogFragment class provides all the controls you need to create
>   your dialog and manage its appearance, instead of calling methods on
>   the Dialog object